# Incremental crawl in subsite doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, crawl

In SharePoint 2013, i've a site collection with some subsite. I added a content source for searching.
I configure full crawl one time per week and incremental crawl every 5 minutes.

If i add a document in parent site, 5 minutes later i see it in search result but if i do the same in the subsite, nothing appear.
(I search from parent site)

If i do a full crawl, i can see the document from subsite.

Do you know what can i do?

thans

Comment: In the content source there is an option to crawl all the content under a given path, give a look at it

Comment: Hi, it's configure and full crawl work but incremental crawl doesn't work